# Wordpress check if user is logged in works wrong

Tags: php, html, wordpress

[image: Click to see the schema here!]

I'm making an advertisement service, I'm using wordpress template. It works fine, but from a week I realise that I've a problem, I don't know when I destroy something.

When I'll post new ad the page is checking if am I logged in.

```
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {   

    $login = $redux_demo['login'];
    wp_redirect( $login ); exit;
} else {
}
```

And mostly it redirect me into Login page (I'm logged in).
On the Login page it checks:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    global $redux_demo;
    $profile = $redux_demo['profile'];
    wp_redirect( $profile ); exit;
}
```

And it is redirecting me into Profile page! So in the first time it return that I'm not logged in, but on the second page it return that I'm logged in.
Sometimes it works. For example when I login and wait a few minutes it works correctly, but when I sign out and login there's the same problem. Do you have some ideas how to fix it?

Comment: You check first time is probably somewhere too early. What action exactly is it hooked to?

Comment: It's the first thing in my php section, on the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice for redirecting is to use the WordPress action event hook called [`template_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect).   This event ensures that you are:

- Checking for the user's login state after that information is available (i.e. and not too early in the load process)
- WordPress is ready to accept a redirect

In your use case, you would want to do the following:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_to_login_page_if_not_logged_in');
/**
 * Redirect to the login page if the user is not logged in.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 * @return void
 */
function redirect_to_login_page_if_not_logged_in() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return;
    }

    global $redux_demo;

    if ( isset( $redux_demo['login'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( esc_url( $redux_demo['login'] ) );
        exit();
    }

    // Redirect to the built-in WordPress login page
    auth_redirect();
}
```

If the user is logged in, just bail out (with the `return`). Else, check if the 'login' key is set in your global variable.  If yes, redirect to that page.  Else, redirect to the built-in WordPress login page using [`auth_redirect()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/auth_redirect).

Comment: Where should I paste this code? In my New Ad file? I paste it instad of 
`if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {   

    $login = $redux_demo['login'];
    wp_redirect( $login ); exit;
} else {
}`
but now I can enter to the page even if I'm not logged in.

Comment: @PawełLeżoch You'll want the above code in the template you are using for the ad.  Yes, you replace that code.  You'll want to do the same for other authorization code too.

Comment: It still doesn't works. I'm still fighting with it. I paste this code, but the site don't do it, I write inside this function:  wp_redirect( 'http://www.google.com'); 
But it doesn't redirect me. It look's like this function is not "visible", it is not performed.

Comment: @PawełLeżoch At this point, you need to discover why the redirect is not happening in your project.  Check if does the global `$redux_demo` exists and, if yes, does it have an element with the key `login`.  Notice that it is wrapped within a gatekeeper (conditional `if` codeblock).  The redirect only happens _if_ the login in `$redux_demo` is set.

Comment: But this doesn't works too:
`function redirect_to_login_page_if_not_logged_in() {
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
wp_redirect( 'http://www.google.com' );
return;
    }
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
wp_redirect( 'http://www.ebay.com' ); return;
}`
It looks like some problems with `is_user_logged_in()`. But I've no idea what is this problem.